# How to enter Hungarian characters ő (long ö) and ű (long ü) on a Mac with German keyboard layout?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, internationalization, character-map

I found that I can write characters with single acute accent, but there is no double acute accent present on my German keyboard. What is the simplest and shortest workaround to enter ő (long ö) and ű (long ü) on a Mac with German keyboard?

I have a 2018 MacBook Pro 15".

Is it possible to script something that picks the letters from the character map?

Comment: Have you tried holding the o or u key, to see if it is shown in the list of accents?

Comment: @benwiggy The two he needs are not in the Accent Menu in German Standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If** you are running Big Sur or later versions of macOS, see this easier and perfect answer:

[How to type ő and ű on a german keyboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461011/22003)

**Else** these 2 characters ő and ű aren't accessible from the German keyboard.

The easiest way for you to type them is to open
 > System Preferences… > Keyboard, then click on the `[+]` button on the bottom left to add the `Hungarian`
keyboard.
And select `Show input menu in menu bar` so as to be able to switch when needed from your German keyboard maping to the `Hungarian` one.

Then when you will need any of these 2 characters, just select from your new drop down menu the hungarian keyboard:

[image: select hungarian keyboard]

Next select also `Show keyboard viewer`:

[image: show keyboard viewer]

And with this keyboard you will find directly accessible all the hungarian characters you may want:

[image: hungarian keyboard viewer]

Once you have been able to type all the hungarian characters you might want, just switch back to your German keyboard. And just close the `keyboard viewer`

Answer (score 6):

With your Input Source set to German Standard, you can type these characters by pressing <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and then the base letter (`u` or `o`).  To see these and other possibilities, you can use [Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0).

Apple added its German Standard input source with macOS Big Sur in 2020. Prior versions only had a German layout which cannot produce the Hungarian characters.

Note that in Apple's German Standard, the @ character moves from <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> to <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>. It also includes the capital eszett ẞ.  But it is not identical to the real [German DIN standard](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_2137).

[image: Image of keyboard layout]

Comment: @TomGewecke "German – Standard" is not the default German keyboard layout. Look at a [current Apple keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK2A3D/A/magic-keyboard-german). "Standard" refers not to being the default but to [DIN 2137](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_2137), a new standard from December 2018, as [I tried to add](https://apple.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/338240). The symbol layer is completely reordered compared to the normal German keyboard layout.  The usability of "German – Standard" depends on how well you already have internalized the normal symbol layer.

Comment: @cachius You are right that Apple’s “Standard”  differs from the actual DIN version.  It is the default in the sense that it is the input source which matches the printing on Apple German hardware keyboards since 2020 or so.

Comment: @TomGewecke It isn't, [checkout](https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4668/as-images.apple.com/is/mba15-midnight-gallery3-202306_GEO_EMEA_LANG_DE?wid=2000&hei=1537&fmt=jpeg&qlt=75&.v=1684875904475 "Bird's eye view of the 15-inch MacBook Air 2023 with German keyboard layout. It has the @-character still on the letter L.") the [new 15-inch MacBook Air](https://www.apple.com/de/shop/buy-mac/macbook-air/15-zoll-mitternacht-apple-m2-chip-mit-8-core-cpu-und-10-core-gpu-512gb "15\" MacBook Air – Mitternacht. German MacBook version in the Apple online shop")

Comment: @cachius You seem to be correct. Apple's Magic Keyboard image also has @ printed on the L now. I could swear they have had it printed on Q in recent years. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can type characters by entering their hex codes with the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout. The layout could be added in *System Settings > Keyboard > Input Sources*.

To write characters using their hex codes with the Unicode Hex Input keyboard layout, hold the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key while typing the hex code of the wanted character.

The hex code for `ű` is U+0170 and the hex code for `ő` is U+0151.

- ű - hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and type: **0170**
- ő - hold <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and type: **0151**

Comment: @TomGewecke No. That was my mistake. I’ve used a custom keyboard layout.